# Why is the imported TIFF file distorted with noise in Quantum-GIS?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, aerial-photography, orthophoto, noise

I've a TIFF-file. Loading the raster image into QGIS does not display correctly. (Using the `Add raster layer` button.) It seems to be distorted with noise. See image below:

[image: qgis (l), image viewer (r)]

The source of the TIFF file is a 300 dpi scanned document. Other scanned documents display correctly.

Projection doesn't matter as the image is not georeferenced yet.

I'm using qgis-1.7.0 in a sabayon-linux environment.

What's the source of this problem? Did anyone else encounter this before? Thanks for any hints or experience on this topic.

Comment: Can you check what raster style is used under Layer Properties -> Style

Comment: Three Band Colour. That's it!

Comment: hmmm can you post a screen shot of that for me

Comment: It's a greyscale image but the import tried to display 3 bands. Your hint was correct. Switching style to single band fixed it and the raster layer displays correct.

Comment: Do you want to post that a answer to you own question.  After 2 days you can accept it.  You will get rep, and it will also close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qgis does not know this is a grey-scale image and tries to display 3 bands.

Opening the `layer properties` and the `style` tab allows you to switch back to grey-scale (`single band grey`) from coloured style (`three band colour`).

Thanks [Nathan W](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/97/nathan-w) for pointing out to check layer style properties.